# Rails :: Why the attribute change doesn't persist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Controller:

```
@events = Event.all
@events.each { |e| e.user_subscribed = "someuser" }
@events.each { |e| puts "error" + e.user_subscribed }
```

I have `attr_accessor :user_subscribed`. but the error is `can't convert nil into String` as e.user_subscribed evaluates to nil.

I'm using mongoid on the backend.

**edit**: this works, but it just copies the whole array.

```
@events = @events.map do |e|
  e.user_subscribed = "faaa"
  e
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not saving the @events to the database, user_subscribed won't persist, unless you keep it in memory:

```
@events_with_subscription = @events.map { |e| e.user_subscribed = "someuser"; return e }
```

Comment: Isn't this really slow? Doesn't it copy **all** the events?

Comment: You could also do this with `map!`. But as mentioned in my response to your previous question, I don't think this is the best way to do what you're trying to acheive :)

Comment: map! doesn't work, map does but it copies the entire @events. I don't want to save this to the database as it's user-centric. Also, instead of `user_subscribed` it will call a model function in the actual code, passing the user, but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

edited based on OP comments.

sounds like it might be better to just output Event.user_subscribed(current_user) directly in the view...but if you wanted to load up all that data before hand you could do:

```
@array_of_subscription_results = @Events.map{|e| e.user_subscribed(current_user,some,other,var,required) }
```

As long as user_subscribed returns the values you are interested in, thats what map will load into @array_of_subscription_results

Comment: `update_attribute` saves it to the database. It's a per user attribute and there's no reason to save it to the db. How can you tweak map? i don't want to duplicate the entire array

Comment: it looks like you are iterating through events to assign a value. What are you trying to do? collect a list of all user_subscribed from each event?

Comment: user_subscribed will be a function that will tell if the user is subscribed to the event, based on the current user and a couple of other things. After this I want to pass it to the view.

Comment: edited the original item to hopefully reflect what you are looking for if user_subscribed is a function instead of a field

Comment: Isn't calling the model from the view discouraged? And how would I do this in JSON output?

Comment: It's just weird.. it breaks DRY (will have to do this in the controller for JSON).